# How can I connect another website with mine and get its information?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cross-domain

I´d like to connect my website with another and want to get its information.

So the user shall be able to login to the other website via mine and I would like

to read out the users information, for example the friendcount on Facebook.

I can imagine a javascript command but how can I read the information of the

other website?

thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't a generic solution. You'll need the site to provide an API that exposes the information you want and then follow the documentation for it.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try curl on php with a curl http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php, but it depends on what you want to do so be more specific please

Comment: The example given in the question is getting the friend count from Facebook, and you can't get that information with PHP. While you could make an HTTP request from cURL, it wouldn't provide that information.